# Use a ProgressBar as a StackPanel background

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

In my WPF project I want to use a ProgressBar as a StackPanel background, taking along all the other elements. is there any way to set it as the background of the stackpanel element?
Thank you :D

[Image of the XAML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrucJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`VisualBrush`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualbrush?view=net-5.0) like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <VisualBrush>
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Canvas>
                    <ProgressBar Value="50"></ProgressBar>
                </Canvas>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </StackPanel.Background>
</StackPanel>
```

#### P.S.

Please post your code as text and not as images